# Can machines be "shutdown guest OS" without having VMware Tools installed using Powershell?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, powershell-4.0, vsphere, system-shutdown

I need to shut down "Guest OS" of machines in powershell.
I dont have VMware Tools installed on the guest to use `Shutdown-VMGuest`.

**My question is can this be done without installing VMWare tools on the guest. Is this even a possible ?**

If NOT: **Are there any other commands (like `soft power operation`, but i dont really understand this) OR any other ways to do this ?**

If NOT: **Is there any equivalent of "Shutdown guest OS" that can be done in powershell ?**

It does look like i am posting 3 questions, but i want to just be able to shutdown guest os of vms bypassing installing VMWare tools using powershell.

PS: I am new to this, please be kind if this seems like a stupid question :)

Answer (score 3):

The shutdown guest OS is a vmware tools option, and the benefit is that it is OS independent, as long as the vmware tools are installed it works.

PowerShell has the stop-computer command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer?view=powershell-7

You could use the -computername option for a remote machine.

```
-ComputerName

Specifies the computers to stop. The default is the local computer.

Type the NETBIOS name, IP address, or fully qualified domain name of one or more computers in a comma-separated list. To specify the local computer, type the computer name or localhost.

This parameter doesn't rely on PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter even if your computer isn't configured to run remote commands.
```

PS. I'm assuming a WIndows Based OS here, correct?

Answer (score 1):

VMware player may have the option for shutdown/restart guest OS even no VMTools is installed in the guest? (to be confirmed though)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32125559)